# Переопределения стандартных свойств через CSS

Tags: css

Как переопределить стандартные записи CSS на подобие `:hover`, `:up`, `:down` и т.д.? Если я прописываю нечто подобное в стилях:

```
.myClass:hover {        
      somestyle:value;         
}
```

то это свойство не применяется.

Comment: Какое то сплощное угадывание и гадание на кофейной гуще ...

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, IE до 6 версии включительно не понимает :hover для не-ссылок.
Во-вторых, с каких времен :up и :down стали стандартными конструкциями CSS?
И, в-третьих, проверьте ваш CSS-код. Возможно, где-то в нем прописан селектор того же элемента, но более детально. То есть, #id .class будет рассчитан после .class и, следовательно, перекроет его правила. Посмотрите сгенерированную страницу Firebug'ом или Хромовским инспектором - они отображают перекрываемые правила.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй поставить повышенный приоритет, вот так:

```
.myClass:hover{        
  somestyle: value !important;         
}
```

Ставлю на то, что заработает :)

Comment: Не помогло.

Comment: Значит не тому элементу/не то свойство задаете, имхо... Хотя вариантов может быть куча.

Answer (score 0):

Должно работать.

Если только для данного элемента не стоит более приоритетный селектор.

Создайте тестовую страницу и посмотрите результат.
Например вот. Всё работает: http://pastehtml.com/view/1ejpipt.html

Comment: Обратите внимание на тег **GWT**.

Comment: Какая разница ? В конечном итоге(на выходе) это всё равно html

Comment: Не подхватываются так. Возможно, надо что-то указать.

Comment: Разница в том, что, будучи фреймворком, он предусматривает свои правила приоритета, в том числе какие стили загружать в каком порядке. @javer может быть проблема в том, что системные стили грузятся раньше ваших?

Comment: Проверял, мои стили подгружаются после основных.